# Programming with Dplyr: How to make a function that can be used in a for loop?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

**Goal**

I'm trying to create a function that creates a custom cross table (a.k.a. pivot table). To do this I'm using the `rlang` package, trying to stick to the "dplyr" way of programming. See also http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html.

**The function**

```
library(tidyverse)

crossTable <- function(
  df,
  rows,
  cols,
  vals
){

  quoRows = enquo(rows)
  quoCols = enquo(cols)
  quoVals = enquo(vals)

  result <-
    df %>%
    group_by(!!quoRows, !!quoCols) %>%
    summarize(
      values = !!quoVals
    ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    spread(!!quoCols, values)

}
```

**What works**

Calling this function in the global environment works.

```
a <- crossTable(mpg, manufacturer, cyl, mean(hwy))
a
```

**What doesn't work**

I would like to be able to use this function to automatically generate different cross tables for different `rows`, `cols`, and `vals`, for example by using a for loop or one of the `map` functions (the tidyverse equivalent to the base `apply` functions). In other words I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
b <- list()

colVars <- c(cyl, class)

expr <- c(mean(hwy), mean(cty), median(hwy), median(cty))

for(i in seq_along(colVars)){

  for(j in seq_along(expr)){

    b[[i]][[j]] <- crossTable(mpg, manufacturer, colVars[[i]], expr[[j]])

  }

}
```

For the `rows` and `cols` I have seen some people use `group_by_at`, but that still doens't solve the problem for `vals`.

**My questions**

- How can I change this function so that it also works in a for loop (or when called with `map`/`apply`)?
- Alternatively, if it is too difficult to make it work using the dplyr way (using `enquo` and friends), what would be a "base" way to solve this?

Comment: Did you do some `attach` i.e. `colVars <- c(cyl, class)` is not working for me unless the objects are created

Comment: dplyr-esque cross tabs are provided in the janitor package. You may find the crosstab function from that package useful. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: @akrun No I did not use some form of attach. the fact that `colVars <- c(cyl, class)` is not working is exactly what my problem is. I can do `colVars <- c("cyl", "class")` and `expr <- c("mean(hwy)", "mean(cty)", "median(hwy)", "median(cty)")`, but then the function doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to convert the 'expr' to quosures and then within the loop, evaluate the arguments with `!!` along with conversion of character vector ('colVars') to `sym` ('symbol')

```
colVars <- c("cyl", "class")
b <- vector('list', length(colVars))
expr <- quos(mean(hwy), mean(cty), median(hwy), median(cty))
for(i in seq_along(colVars)){

  for(j in seq_along(expr)){

    b[[i]][[j]] <- crossTable(mpg, manufacturer, !!rlang::sym(colVars[i]), !! expr[[j]])

  }

}
```

-checking the output

```
identical(crossTable(mpg, manufacturer, cyl, mean(hwy)), b[[1]][[1]])
#[1] TRUE
identical(crossTable(mpg, manufacturer, cyl, mean(cty)), b[[1]][[2]])
#[1] TRUE
identical(crossTable(mpg, manufacturer, cyl, median(hwy)), b[[1]][[3]])
#[1] TRUE
identical(crossTable(mpg, manufacturer, cyl, median(cty)), b[[1]][[4]]) 
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This looks really impressive! I didn't know you could do this. The problem I still have is that it's a bit difficult to work with for other users. (I don't think they'll be eager to use quosure vectors.) I'm really looking for a "simple" solution (from a user perspective). It's ok if the function accepts strings instead of expressions for example. I'm just not sure how to get that to work with the `summarize` which needs an expression.

Comment: @Willem  Thanks, but your `crossTable` function is using `quosure`s.  So, I got the impression that you want a tidyverse approach.  I understand that you mentioned base R alternatives.

Comment: true in that sense this is the answer to the question. Meanwhile your answer (specifically `rlang::sym`) showed me the way to make it work using strings. In short: now instead of `enquo` I use `rlang::sym` for `rows` and `cols`. For `vals` I use `rlang::parse_expr`. This allows me to pass on strings which you can put in a vector, which was really the crux of the problem for me. In any case thx for your help!